# Computing van Kampen diagrams

Tags: gr.group-theory, computational-complexity, combinatorial-group-theory

If G is a finitely presented group  (with generating set X) and w is a word over X such that
w=1 in G, then the latter can be witnessed by a so called van Kampen diagram for w, which is
a planar diagram where for each region the boundary cycle is labelled with a group relator,
and the boundary of the whole diagram is labelled with the word w.

Is there a finitely presented group G (with generating set X) such that the following hold?

- G has polynomial Dehn function
- G has a polynomial time word problem
- There is no polynomial time algorithm for the following problem:

  INPUT: A word w over X such that w=1 in G

  OUTPUT: A van Kampen diagram for w

In other words: We can efficiently check whether w=1 in G but we cannot compute efficiently a witness for this fact (but we know that a small witness exists).

If the answer to the above question is positive, one certainly needs some complexity theoretic assumption. A reasonable starting point might be to assume that a nondeterministic
polynomial time Turing machine M exists such that:

- One can check in deterministic polynomial time whether an input w is accepted by M.
- There is no polynomial time Turing machine that computes for a given word w (that is
  accepted by M) an accepting computation of M for input w.

Comment: The assumption in the last paragraph is simply $\mathrm P\ne\mathrm{NP}$, or am I missing something?

Comment: Since you can move from a van Kampen diagram using one presentation to another in polynomial time, I think this question is independent of $X$, so you are just looking for a suitable group. Since verifying the correctness of a candidate diagram can be done in polynomial time, perhaps the best you can hope for is to find an example in which you could prove the problem was NP-complete. But I've no idea how to look for suitable candidates!

Comment: Yes, since any group with polynomial Dehn function has word problem in NP (and the certificate is more or less a van Kampen diagram), it seems like an answer to the question would imply $P\neq NP$. Could you clarify the connection?

Comment: @Emil: I am not sure, whether the assumption implies that P and NP are different. I thought its more a condition similar

Comment: For any nondeterministic poly-time machine $M$, given an input $w$ you can compute an accepting computation of $M$ on $w$ (if one exists) in $\mathrm{FP}^{\mathrm{NP}}$ by binary search. If P = NP, this is just polynomial time.

Comment: @Emil: Do you also think that P≠NP implies that a machine as described in my post exists? From your previous comment, I can only see that P = NP implies that a machine as described in my post cannot exist (since if NP=P one can compute accepting computations paths for NP-machines in polynomial time).

Comment: Ah, now I noticed what I was missing, namely the requirement that the machine, although nondeterministic, actually computes a language in P. Sorry. You can assume without loss of generality that your $M$ accepts every input. Then it should be clear that the existence of such a machine is equivalent to the existence of a total NP-search problem that cannot be solved in polynomial time (i.e., FP ≠ TFNP). This is a stronger assumption than P ≠ NP, but it is implied by P ≠ NP ∩ coNP, or for that matter, by the existence of one-way permutations.

Comment: @Emil: Thanks a lot for the explanation. I was quite sure that my condition is equivalent to a known complexity theoretic assumption, but I was not sure which one.

Comment: @HJRW: Indeed, the existence of a finitely presented group as in my post implies that P≠NP, but not necessarily the other way round. To deduce the existence of group as in my post one needs probably a stronger complexity theoretic assumption as Emil remarked in his last comment.

Answer (score 6):

This is equivalent to $P\ne NP$ by the result of the paper : Birget, J.-C.; Olʹshanskii, A. Yu.; Rips, E.; Sapir, M. V. Isoperimetric functions of groups and computational complexity of the word problem. Ann. of Math. (2) 156 (2002), no. 2, 467–518.

**Update** See the discussion [here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307629/is-this-conjecture-strictly-weaker-than-p-np)